# React native Undefined is not an object(evaluating'_react3.default.PropType.shape')

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, react-native

I'm studying with React-native due to this case I want to create navigation for IOS and Android, Actually, I meet an error

Error: **React native Undefined is not an object(evaluating'_react3.default.PropType.shape')**

My Develop environment

- OS: MACOS Sierra
- Clie: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- React-native version: react-native: 0.49.3

I follow the official react-native [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/using-navigators.html)

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Navigator from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';
import MyScene from './src/components/navigation/MyScene';



const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'IOS: Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Android : Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <Navigator initialRoute={{ title: 'My Initial Scene', index: 0 }}
                renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
                    <MyScene
                        title={route.title}

                        // Function to call when a new scene should be displayed
                        onForward={() => {

                            const nextIndex = route.index + 1;
                            navigator.push({
                                title: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
                                index: nextIndex,
                            });
                        }}

                        // Function to call to go back to the previous scene
                        onBack={() => {
                            if (route.index > 0) {
                                navigator.pop();
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                }
            />
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 50,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

MyScene.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class MyScene extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Current Scene: {this.props.title}</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onForward}>
                    <Text>Tap me to load the next scene</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onBack}>
                    <Text>Tap me to go back</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

MyScene.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onForward: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onBack: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: PropTypes has remove from react in the latest version. so you need to use and other package.

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: is it difference or not between reactjs and react native?

Comment: yes, it difference. but react-native is depend on react js.
Same usage just difference some UI component only. 
Ex. <div/> and <View/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your version of react, 
If the version is > 16 then propTypes is inside a new package called `prop-types`

see : https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",

Comment: the do 

` npm i --save prop-types `

and then in your component

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

Comment: I have the same problem and i also tried to do that, but the problem still happens. I inserted the "import" line inside the file: "NavigatorBreadcrumbNavigationBar.js", Did i miss something?

Comment: @ROI I am having the same issue here with NavigatorBreadcrumbNavigationBar.js. Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: same issue here. I have prop-types installed. If I made a test.js file and require('prop-types') it finds it. But running both on ios and android gives me this error with NavigatorBreadcrumbNavigationBar.js

Comment: @drew-jex the issue is due to a bug in the npm published version of react-native-deprecated-custom-components.  There is a fix in the github repo for this. An explanation can be found in this issue: https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-custom-components/issues/21