# React native Undefined is not an object(evaluating'_react3.default.PropType.shape')?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using react-native build android project, and use 'Navigator'. when I look at  version > react@44.0 should be used:

`import { Navigator } from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';`

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import TabNavigator from 'react-native-tab-navigator';
import {
   Navigator
} from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Boy from './boy';

const instructions = Platform.select({
   ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
   'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
   android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
   'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
          selectedTab: 'tab_polular'
       }
    }
   render() {
       return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
         <Navigator
             initialRoute = {
                 {component: Boy}
             }
             renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
                 let Component = route.component;
                 return <Component navigator={navigator} {...route.params}/>
             }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
```

get this error:

[image]

and I see this question with similar about me [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781664/react-native-undefined-is-not-an-objectevaluating-react3-default-proptype-shap)
add this code in `app.js`:

`import PropTypes from 'prop-types`

but error also has here!

how to resolve the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok， i'm find the error reason:

because react version too height.

my project react version==='16.0.0'

`react: 16.0.0`

if resolve the error, react version must be:

`"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12"`

then:

`react-native run ios`

Answer (score 0):

You can find some info about this issue [here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-custom-components/issues/21), but i will try gather the info nicely for you

But basically, if your version of react > 16, you must run `npm i --save prop-types` and then in your code include `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`

if your version of react < 16, you must import PropTypes from React like so `import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';`

You can check your version of React by going to the project directory, opening up your `package.json` file, and it should be there. Should look something like this:

`"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",`

Comment: my react version=== '16.0.0', so i should use `import react, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react`?

Comment: nah you should use the first option. Have you installed `prop-types` ?

Comment: yeah, see here `package.json`[package](http://oo8hp4ueg.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-12-15_164535.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install react-native-deprecated-custom-components --save`
2. change the [Navigator.js](https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-custom-components/blob/master/src/Navigator.js) file to the latest version(come from facebook)